# Convert date time into correct date time format of dd-MMM-yyyy HH:MM in dojo

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo

I am getting my current date time in below format

```
Fri Oct 04 2019 13:48:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But i need this in below format

```
04-Oct-2019 19:18
```

I am getting first format

```
exports.date = function formatDate(vpDateObj) {
  var vpDate = locale.parse(dateUtils.toString(vpDateObj), {
    datePattern: "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm",
    selector: "date"
  });
  alert(vpDate);
  alert(convert(vpDate));
  return vpDate ? vpDate.toString(vpDate) : " ";
};
```

and i am trying to convert into proper format like below

```
function convert(str) {
  var date = new Date(str),
    mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  hours = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
  minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day, hours, minutes].join("-");
}
```

But here `GMT+530 hours` is not getting added in time.

Please help

Comment: Why do you want to add GMT 5:30 instead of subtracting, IST is `5 hrs 30 mins` ahead of GMT not behind.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure what you need is here is to convert that locale date **`IST`** into **`GMT`** (which is equivalent to **`UTC`** there is no quantifiable difference between the two) in the required format **`dd-MMM-yyyy HH:MM`**

```js
function dateConverter(d) {
  const monthList = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];

  /*Notice UTC methods are used to take care of 1st day of month and year*/
  const yr = d.getUTCFullYear();
  const mnt = monthList[d.getUTCMonth()];
  const day = d.getUTCDate() < 9 ? "0" + d.getUTCDate() : d.getUTCDate();

  const gmtHr = d.getUTCHours();
  const gmtMin =
d.getUTCMinutes() < 9 ? "0" + d.getUTCMinutes() : d.getUTCMinutes();

  return [day, mnt, yr].join("-") + " " + [gmtHr, gmtMin].join(":");
}
const result = dateConverter(new Date());
//alert("Formatted::" + result);
console.info("Formatted::", result);
```

Comment: i am getting error like `const definition are not supported with current java script version`

Comment: @SUDARSHAN Try changing those `const` with `var`.  That I am guessing is because of `dojo`

Comment: @SUDARSHAN How are you printing it in `alert`? I've updated the above answer with `alert` as well but commented, it does print formatted date as well as time. Did changing `const` with `var` work?

Comment: No it did not work ..I have changed the implementation itself but stuck again at one point ..Created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282149/not-able-to-convert-string-bst-date-format-to-utc-in-javascript

Comment: @SUDARSHAN Okay! That's odd. Not sure why it didn't work although u've changed the implementation it does what was asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use locale.format, be aware that idian time is ahead of GMT by 5h30 not backward

should minus 5h30 hour :

```js
require(["dojo/date/locale"
], function(locale) {
  var vpDate  = new Date("Fri Oct 04 2019 15:48:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
  
  console.log(vpDate);
  
  var format3 = locale.format( vpDate , {selector:"date", datePattern:"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm " } );
    
  
  console.log("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm -> ",format3);
  
});
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
  dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: true,
    async: true
  };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```